# Minecraft inventory when shift and drag mouse won't put items into other inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the right mouse button and drag it to auto-put all the items, but my mouse goes over into the other inventory (chest, etc.) and it won't work. Does this maybe happen because I am using version 1.16.1?

Comment: I think your `f` key is broken.

Comment: I was unaware that shift + right click did anything. Are you sure you don't mean shift + left click?

Answer (score 2):

Shift + Left Click items individually is to quick-transfer. What you're describing is a feature of [Inventory Tweaks](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/inventory-tweaks), but is usually done with the Left mouse button (whatever Button 1 is assigned to).

Shift + Right Click + Drag with an item already grabbed quick-places one item per slot hovered over. Shift + Left Click + Drag does the same, but has the stacks equally spread out, with the remainder staying in hand.

There is also a known bug prior to 1.14 where in certain cases, losing focus of the window breaks all UI events in inventories until you restarted Minecraft.

Comment: worth adding: shift+doubleclick while holding (any, unrelated) item moves all stacks of the item type you double-clicked on to the other inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're trying to spread items equally in a chest then I'm pretty sure you need to press the scroll wheel, not the right mouse button.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is wrong anyway, i think you just drag